# nginx stream балансировка

Tags: nginx, сервер, веб-сервер, прокси, балансировка

Помогите прояснить ситуацию. Есть, к примеру подобный конфиг

```
stream {
    server {
        listen  443;
            proxy_pass 192.168.10.1:443; 
    }   

    server {
        listen  3443;
            proxy_pass 192.168.10.1:3443; 
    } 
}

    server {
        listen  8443;
            proxy_pass 192.168.10.1:8443; 
    } 
}
```

Все прекрасно работает. Но хочется сделать балансировку до нескольких бэкендов. Вся проблема в том, что если первый запрос ушел на 443 по 192.168.10.1, то и по остальным портам нужно отправлять запрос ИСКЛЮЧИТЕЛЬНО на тот-же самый IP. Я правильно понимаю (может это колхоз, и все делается проще?) - для каждого порта делать свой upstream, в итоге у нас 3 апстрим секции. Но вот только как сделать так, чтобы от одного клиента все запросы железобетонно уходили на один и тот-же сервер, который до этого выберется не раунд-робином, а по принципу наименьшего количества коннектов к нему?

Comment: Для этого теоретически нужно где-то как-то хранить таблицу соответствий клиент->апстрим, но при большой посещаемости она быстро сожрёт всю память, так что подозреваю, что в таком виде без дополнительных допущений желаемое вами сделать технически невозможно. Даже запомнить нужный апстрим в куках клиента не получится, потому что на разных портах будут разные куки

Comment: В предыдущем вопросе уже написали, в stream есть только ip клиента и может быть hostname. Причём вообще говоря, никто не обещает, что на другой порт клиент придёт с тем же ip. Так что вы хотите странного и в общем случае невозможного.

Comment: (а, я проглядел, что тут ещё и stream, тогда даже упомянутых мной кук нету, мде)